# Reading XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","C:\ARKData.xml",false)
```

When I run this line, I get:

> file:///C:/Users/galisetti.ramesh/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary%20Internet%20Files/FrontPageTempDir/pvw2E.htm invalid argument error

Comment: Are you sure that ARKData.xml is actually a file and not some kind of shortcut or alias to that file?  What's awkward is that the error is pointing to a temporary an html file in a temporary directory.  What does your browser's console / network profiler output when you run the script?

Comment: Does js allow local file system access? That looks like a security issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem here is likely the backslash in your string; use a forward slash `/` instead.

That said, modern browsers are extremely picky with local filesystem requests. If it works at all, your document will have to reside in the same directory, or a parent directory, as the resource you're calling.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant when I said browsers are picky with those kinds of requests. Does your document fulfill the requirements about where it has to be located?